# R multivariate one step ahead forecasts and accuracy

Tags: r, time-series, prediction

Using R I would like to compare the RMSE (root mean square error) from two prediction models.  The first model uses estimates from 1966 to 2000 to predict 2001 and then uses estimates from 1966 to 2001 to predict 2002 and so on up to 2015.  The second model uses estimates from 1991 to 2000 to predict 2001 and then uses estimates from 1992 to 2001 to predict 2002 and so on up to 2015.  This problem has me really stumped and I truly appreciate any help.

```
DF <- data.frame(YEAR=1966:2015, TEMP=rnorm(50), PRESSURE=rnorm(50), RAINFALL=rnorm(50))

lmod <- lm(TEMP ~ PRESSURE + RAINFALL, data = DF)

rmse <- function(error) sqrt(mean(error^2))

rmse(lmod$residuals)
```

Comment: What goes wrong when you run the code you have there?

Comment: My code is just an ordinary regression model.  It does not do any one step ahead predictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop it:

Method 1:

```
pred1<-numeric(0)
rmse1<-numeric(0)

for(i in 1:15){

DF.train1<-DF[DF$YEAR < 2000+i,]
DF.test1<-DF[DF$YEAR == 2000+i,]
lmod1 <- lm(TEMP ~ PRESSURE + RAINFALL, data = DF.train1)
pred1[i]<- predict(lmod1, newdata = DF.test1)
rmse1[i]<-sqrt(mean((DF.test1$TEMP-pred1[i])^2))
}

pred1
rmse1  
mean(rmse1)
```

Method 2:

```
pred2<-numeric(0)
rmse2<-numeric(0)

for(i in 1:15){

DF.train2<-DF[DF$YEAR < 2000+i & DF$YEAR > 1989+i,]
DF.test2<-DF[DF$YEAR == 2000+i,]
lmod2 <- lm(TEMP ~ PRESSURE + RAINFALL, data = DF.train2)
pred2[i]<- predict(lmod2, newdata = DF.test2)
rmse2[i]<-sqrt(mean((DF.test2$TEMP-pred2[i])^2))
} 

pred2
rmse2  
mean(rmse2)
```

Comparing the individual components of `rmse1` and `rmse2`, as well as their respective means should be useful. The vectors `pred1` and `pred2` contain the individual `TEMP` predictions for each year (2001-2015) for their respective methods.

Edit: should be working now, and Method 2 trains on a rolling 10 year gap. Also, I take RMSE to be the square root of the MSE as defined for predictors in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) article.

Comment: @Brian Goyggin, I have the same issue of subsetting on forecast using autoarima but if I want to use the first 1966 (in 1966-2000) to predict 2001, 2002..2015 but I also want to use the three years (1966, 1967, 1968) to predict in similar fashion, five years , seven years (up to 2000) to predict 2001…2015, 9 years it goes up to the last year 2000. How can I use if I want to use it in two years intervals starting from 1, i.e (1, 3,5,7,….).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, where simulations are in a function.
The interest of this solution is to easily modify model specifications.

For example, if you want to try the `model2` with a range of 15 years instead of 10, just modify the input in the function (`range = 15`). This also gives you the possibility to do a light sensibility analysis.

```
compare_models <- function(DF, start = 1966, end = 2000, range = 10)
{
  require(hydroGOF)
  for (i in (end+1):tail(DF$YEAR)[6])
  {
   # model1
    lmod_1 = lm(TEMP ~ PRESSURE + RAINFALL, data = DF[DF$YEAR >= start & DF$YEAR < i,])
    DF$model1_sim[DF$YEAR == i] <- predict(lmod_1, newdata = DF[DF$YEAR == i,])
    # model2
    lmod_2 = lm(TEMP ~ PRESSURE + RAINFALL, data = DF[DF$YEAR >= i-range & DF$YEAR < i,])
    DF$model2_sim[DF$YEAR == i] <- predict(lmod_2, newdata = DF[DF$YEAR == i,])
  }
  return(DF)
}
```

I used `hydroGOF` package to compute `rmse` and `NSE`, which is a common indicator of model efficiency (see [Nash and Sutcliffe, 1970](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022169470902556), 11528 citations at the moment).

```
output = compare_models(DF)

require(hydroGOF) # compute RMSE and NSE
# RMSE 
rmse(output$model1_sim,output$TEMP)
rmse(output$model2_sim,output$TEMP)

# Nash-Sutcliffe efficiency
NSE(output$model1_sim,output$TEMP, na.rm = T)
NSE(output$model2_sim,output$TEMP, na.rm = T)
```

And a simple simulated/observed plot to look for model predictions:

```
# melting data for plot
output_melt = melt(output[,c("TEMP", "model1_sim", "model2_sim")], id = "TEMP")
# Plot
ggplot(output_melt, aes(x = TEMP, y = value, color = variable)) + 
theme_bw() + geom_point() + geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 0) + 
xlim(-2,2) + ylim(-2,2) + xlab("Measured") + ylab("Simulated")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another solution:

```
year <- 2000
time.frame <- 35


train.models <- function(year, time.frame) {
   predictions <- sapply(year:(max(df$YEAR)-1), 
          function(year) {
             lmod <- lm(TEMP ~ PRESSURE + RAINFALL, DF,
                        subset = with(DF, YEAR %in% (year - time.frame + 1):year))

             pred <- predict(lmod, newdata = DF[DF$YEAR == (year + 1),])
             names(pred) <- year + 1
             return (pred)
          })

   return (predictions)
}

models1 <- train.models(2000, 35)
models2 <- train.models(2001, 10)


rmse(models1 - DF$TEMP[DF$YEAR %in% names(models1)])
rmse(models2 - DF$TEMP[DF$YEAR %in% names(models2)])
```