# Subsetting time series in two years interval using R

Tags: r

I want to develop the model using autoarima and I have time-series data from 1970 to 2015. I just want to look at how it predicts using one-year data (1970) and then predict 2005, use three-year data (1970, 1971,1972) to predict 2005 or 2006, use five-year data (1970, 1971,1972,1973, 1974 (training sets)... and it continues with two yeas interval (like 1,3,5,7..years of data)until 2015 to predict one year out (testing sets). I am having difficulty in coding but I have got the following important link on Stackoverflow, I can't modify it. This problem of subsetting drive me crazy, please help me out. I have got this good source from the StackOverflow for what I am thinking of,  but how do I customize it to my case? 
[R multivariate one step ahead forecasts and accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37661829/r-multivariate-one-step-ahead-forecasts-and-accuracy)

```
pred2<-numeric(0)
rmse2<-numeric(0)

for(i in 1:15){

DF.train2<-DF[DF$YEAR < 2000+i & DF$YEAR > 1989+i,]
DF.test2<-DF[DF$YEAR == 2000+i,]
lmod2 <- lm(TEMP ~ PRESSURE + RAINFALL, data = DF.train2)
pred2[i]<- predict(lmod2, newdata = DF.test2)
rmse2[i]<-sqrt(mean((DF.test2$TEMP-pred2[i])^2))
} 

pred2
rmse2  
mean(rmse2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider elementwise loop with `Map` (wrapper to `mapply`) between two pairs of train years and test years for subsetting:

**Year Values**

```
test_yrs <- lapply(c(2005:2015), function(i) c(2005:i) )

train_yrs <- lapply(seq(1,(2015-1970), by=2), function(i) 
     c(1970:2004)[c(1:i)] 
)[seq_along(test_yrs)]


train_yrs    

# [[1]]
# [1] 1970
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1970 1971 1972
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 1970 1971 1972 1973 1974
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 1970 1971 1972 1973 1974 1975 1976
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 1970 1971 1972 1973 1974 1975 1976 1977 1978
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] 1970 1971 1972 1973 1974 1975 1976 1977 1978 1979 1980
# 
# [[7]]
# [1] 1970 1971 1972 1973 1974 1975 1976 1977 1978 1979 1980 1981 1982
# 
# [[8]]
# [1] 1970 1971 1972 1973 1974 1975 1976 1977 1978 1979 1980 1981 1982 1983 1984
# 
# [[9]]
# [1] 1970 1971 1972 1973 1974 1975 1976 1977 1978 1979 1980 1981 1982 1983 1984 1985 1986
# 
# [[10]]
# [1] 1970 1971 1972 1973 1974 1975 1976 1977 1978 1979 1980 1981 1982 1983 1984 1985 1986 1987 1988
# 
# [[11]]
# [1] 1970 1971 1972 1973 1974 1975 1976 1977 1978 1979 1980 1981 1982 1983 1984 1985 1986 1987 1988 1989 1990


test_yrs

# [[1]]
# [1] 2005
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 2005 2006
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 2005 2006 2007
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 2005 2006 2007 2008
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010
# 
# [[7]]
# [1] 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011
# 
# [[8]]
# [1] 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012
# 
# [[9]]
# [1] 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013
# 
# [[10]]
# [1] 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014
# 
# [[11]]
# [1] 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015
```

**Modeling**

```
model_func <- function(train_yrs, test_yrs) {

   train_df <- df[df$Year %in% train_yrs,]
   test_df <- df[df$Year %in% test_yrs,]

   mod <- lm(DepVar ~ IndepVar1 + IndepVar2 + IndepVar3, data = train_df)

   pred <- predict(mod, newdata = DF.test2),
   rmse <- sqrt(mean((test_df$DepVar - pred)^2))

   return(list(pred = pred, rmse = rmse))
}

results_list <- Map(model_func, train_yrs, test_yrs)

# ALL ELEMENTS
results_list

# ALL pred ELEMENTS
lapply(results_list, `[`, "pred")

# ALL rmse ELEMENTS
lapply(results_list, `[`, "rmse")    

# INDIVIDUAL ELEMENTS
results_list[[1]]$pred
results_list[[1]]$rmse

results_list[[2]]$pred
results_list[[2]]$rmse
...
results_list[[11]]$pred
results_list[[11]]$rmse
```

---

To run above process across multiple data frames, wrap process into a method and call it with `lapply` on list of data frames. Results will be nested under top levels

```
proc_df <- function(df) {
    # NEW PARAM
    model_func <- function(train_yrs, test_yrs, df) {    
       ...
    }

    # ADDED ARG
    results_list <- Map(model_func, train_yrs, test_yrs, MoreArgs=list(df))

    return(results_list)
}

dfs <- list(df1, df2, df3)
df_results_list <- lapply(dfs, proc_df)

# ALL ELEMENTS BY DATA FRAME
df_results_list[[1]]
df_results_list[[2]]
df_results_list[[3]]
```

Comment: thanks a lot!  I will check it, thank you so much! and if I want to repeat this in a loop for three identical data of the same pattern, I wish if you could also give me that hint then, I will be good in everything! If I want in test_yrs for 2005, 2006 (not 2005 and 2006), 2007( not 2005, 2006 and 2007)....how do I go about it? I will try to edit your code! oh, you guru, you clicked my mind and solved one of my major challenges in coding! @Parfait

Comment: Save data frames into a list and run above process in a `lapply` passing `df` into method. See update. As for *test_yrs*, simply assign it the 11 years: `test_yrs <- c(2005:2015)`.

Comment: thanks so much for your time and everything! I will run all you have offered me!!!

Comment: Does the above code also work if my data is arranged in multivariate time series form, like my data is arranged (with the same variables, year and count) and the year like from 1970, 1971.....2015, 1970, 1971, ......2015, 1970 1971,...2015... in one column and the measured variable (count) in another column?

Comment: Did you run the code and check yourself if it works?

Comment: @Parafit, 1. Do I have to still allocate memory at the beginning of the function even if I use your code completely? 2. I have changed the argument of rmse to, mae<- (pred -test_df$Count), it gives me an error (longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length), I still got some values though. 3.I want to attach the indices in the result to know the number of training set used and the error that corresponds to this year, like 1 ( one year of training sets gives this much error), 3-year this much error... , how do I go about that?

Comment: @Parafit, 4. How can I do backwards in the train_yrs? Like in 1970:2004, 2004 to predict 2005, 2004 and 2003 to predict 2005 and other possible values in testing years? If you allow me another question, select any year in a sequence of 1year, 3years, 5years……, to make 1, 2,3, ..year prediction in the testing set, how do I go about it based on your code?
If you help me out with this stuff, and then it will be a Phew for me?

Comment: Please avoid asking too many different questions in one post which future readers may not be able to follow. Consider asking a new question if you need extensions of this one and please make an effort to solve and debug rather than asking for code. Good luck and happy coding!